# Python if userinput is less than every int in list print "you've picked the smallest number"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I'm trying to create a simple code that requests a user input number, compares it to a existing list of 'ints' and adds all numbers smaller than user input from list a to list b and prints list a. However, I want to make it so that if the user inputs a number smaller than every number in the existing list( in this example only 0), I want to print("you have picked the smallest number).

I got it to run but it gives the string for everytime x is > num. Instead I want it to only print the string once if it sees that x > num every time. How do I go about this. This is the code:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = []

num = input("give a number from 0-100:""")

try:
    num = int(num)
    for x in a:
        if x > num:
            print("you've picked the smallest number")
        elif x < num:
            b.append(x)
            print(b)
except ValueError:
    print("not a number")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to break out of the loop when x > num condition is satisfied:

```
for x in a:
    if x > num:
        print("you've picked the smallest number")
        break
    elif x < num:
        b.append(x)
        print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because the

```
print("you've picked the smallest number")
```

inside the for look along with the other condition. Try to take it out of that statement and add it in the end.

(or)

Use the **break** function to break after the printing statement.

That will give the output you are looking for.